# How is it possible to broadcast an ERC20 transfer without actually having any?

Tags: erc-20

There's this transaction https://etherscan.io/tx/0xd6cf7c502afe82491228c5f00929a94fe492c24973c150e7b2593a1e2274f75f

It never got executed on the node and was eventually replaced by a self transaction. If it was indeed executed it'd have failed with insufficient funds error.

My question is, how is it possible to broadcast a transaction without actually having sufficient ERC20 in that wallet?

On checking the token transfer history of the `from` wallet, it's evident that they never had sufficient ERC20 with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can broadcast any transaction as long as it's valid. By valid I mean the tx needs to have the correct nonce and signature, and the owner should have enough ETH to cover gasPrice*gasLimit.

The fact that the tx will revert doesn't really matter. You can send it with the usual method, I think even Metamask allows it (just don't let it estimate the gas).

Answer (score 0):

I just attempted this scenario. Prepare a transaction with the next nonce but really low fee to send 1M USDT to a certain address. Obviously, I don't have 1M USDT. Then broadcast another transaction with the same nonce but with enough fee as a self transaction.

What came to me as a surpise is that the node through which we broadcast the transaction doesn't validate if you have enough USDT balance or not. The validation execution happens when it's included in a block. So for a pending transaction, it keeps saying "Pending transfer of 1M USDT" under ERC20 transfer row and the status is "Dropped & Replaced".

Some scammers use this technique to scam less experienced crypto users who think that they'll soon get that USDT.